How do I restart a Redis Enterprise Cluster properly from a complete shutdown?
I've got a Redis Enterprise Cluster that isn't replicating for me following a full cluster shutdown. This was done to perform maintenance on the underlying physical machines. I understand that it's probably not a good idea to allow cluster members to share hardware for that reason. We also need to be able to handle it when something causes a power failure at the DC.
# rladmin status extra all
CLUSTER:
OK. Cluster master: 2 (10.121.202.63)
Cluster health: OK, [42, 6.0, 1.5]
failures/minute - avg1 42.00, avg15 6.00, avg60 1.50.

CLUSTER NODES:
NODE:ID ROLE   ADDRESS        EXTERNAL_ADDRESS   HOSTNAME  MASTERS SLAVES OVERBOOKING_DEPTH   SHARDS CORES             FREE_RAM         PROVISIONAL_RAM  VERSION   SHA    RACK-ID STATUS
node:1  slave  10.121.202.61  10.121.202.61      rcn001vl  1       0      7.07GB              1/100  4                 13.29GB/15.33GB  7.07GB/12.57GB   7.4.2-54  ****** -       OK
node:2  master 10.121.202.63  10.121.202.63      rcn003vl  0       0      10.58GB             0/100  4                 13.34GB/15.33GB  10.58GB/12.57GB  7.4.2-54  ****** -       OK
*node:3 slave  10.121.202.62  10.121.202.62      rcn002vl  0       1      6.95GB              1/100  4                 13.2GB/15.33GB   6.95GB/12.57GB   7.4.2-54  ****** -       OK

DATABASES:
DB:ID NAME TYPE  MODULE STATUS                SHARDS PLACEMENT REPLICATION PERSISTENCE ENDPOINT                                    EXEC_STATE                                                                                                                                                          EXEC_STATE_MACHINE                                     BACKUP_PROGRESS MISSING_BACKUP_TIME REDIS_VERSION
db:5  dev  redis yes    active-change-pending 1      dense     enabled     aof         redis-****************************** RETRYABLE ERROR: redis:10: cnm_exec:3 remote action failed in SMRedisFailover:demoted_list=9:dead_list=9:dead_nodes= [check_slave] , setting retryable error state. SMRedisFailover:demoted_list=9:dead_list=9:dead_nodes= N/A             N/A                 7.2.3

ENDPOINTS:
DB:ID              NAME            ID                                       NODE                  ROLE                  SSL             WATCHDOG_STATUS
db:5               dev             endpoint:5:1                             node:1                single                All             OK

SHARDS:
DB:ID   NAME           ID           NODE      ROLE    SLOTS      USED_MEMORY      BACKUP_PROGRESS        RAM_FRAG     WATCHDOG_STATUS          STATUS
db:5    dev            redis:10     node:3    slave   0-16383    1.89MB           N/A                    13.52MB      failure detected         ERROR: REPLICATION LINK DOWN

I tried ...
# rlutil start_shards uids=10 ; rlutil retry_bdb uid=5 ; rladmin status extra all

... from the master node after the cluster showed it was up but not replicating. Obviously, I'm looking to figure out how to get the failed replication back up. What can I do?
Note
Yes, I really did start each node one at a time in sequence.
